# c# MailClient to send message throw argument null exception

Tags: c#, email-client, argumentnullexception

When I use MailClient in C# to send an email, it throws argument null exception which indicates my message is null. 
But I confirm my message is a html table instead of null.

Does anyone have similar situation as mine?
I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: It will be better if you provide the code that you are running

Comment: Normally debugging will show you the values before it sends, you can check then as to what its setting to what, and maybe why its thinking something is null.